# Strange behaviour with HTTP/2.0 (Apache-2.4.25)

Tags: apache2, spdy, http2

I recently implemented HTTP/2.0 (yesterday), and while developing my website I have noticed that some requests are being delivered as HTTP/1.1. At first I thought that the fact they are taking `0ms` that maybe it's due the files being in local cache, but then I noticed that actually it's completely random. In my apache2.conf I have used the directive `Protocols h2` **not** `Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1`.

The Firefox console shows;

```
GET https://materialwebdesign.ltd/css/style.css [HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]
GET https://materialwebdesign.ltd/css/material.css [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 0ms]
GET https://materialwebdesign.ltd/css/normalize.min.css [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 0ms]
GET https://materialwebdesign.ltd/css/style.css [HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]
```

What is also confusing is that the response in headers for, lets use material.css, show `X-Firefox-Spdy: h2`.

Can anyone elaborate on this, why is this happening?

Comment: Could you share the relevant apache config for this domain?

Comment: @iwaseatenbyagrue I know it has been over a year since your comment. I decided to go with nginx and the h2 mod for it as it was much easier to get up and running. And it works like a f**king charm, even with mod_wsgi for Flask/Django apps!